# view inside scrollView it is not moving

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` of size 320x412 and inside it an `UIView` of size 280x277.But I tried for hours to make that `View` move up and down when I drag it.If I replace the `UIView` with a `TextView` it is working...I can drag the TextView up and down inside the UIScrollView...but with the View it is not working.

This is how my xib file looks like.The black one is the View I want to make it move inside the UIScrolView.ANy idea why is this not working?

[image]

EDIT: I did this

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,480);
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    scrollView.bounces = YES;
    scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    //myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [scrollView addSubview:myView];
    [myView release];
```

And still not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content size of scrollview greater then scrollview frame height to make the scrollview to scroll vertically. You scrollview height is 412.
Set content size, scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 430);

Answer (score 0):

**ALWAYS resize scrollview.contentSize .....**

and **not** the **scrollview.frame** :===////

good luck! :=)